# Minecraft: Custom symbols on maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

While browsing the Minecraft Wiki, I've stumbled upon a very interesting feature: it states (specifically [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Maps)) that it is possible to add custom symbols (called "decorations") to maps - this looks very, very promising, especially for map-making, but lacks so many important details! What exactly the format of the `type` field? Do `x` and `y` fields relate to global (per-world) or local (per-map) coordinates? And if the latter, then what are their limits? This raises so many questions, and, obviously, it also lacks any examples...

I've tried to google it, but in vain: results are mostly about fancy map decorations, furniture and the staff. Could someone please explain this topic or link to someplace where it is already explained?

Comment: Well ,I don't know, but I'm well off with some [pixel art](http://rudyhoivt.neocities.org/screenshots/2016-09-24_19.03.24.png)

Comment: Yeah, pixel art is awesome... But, sadly, it's not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The available symbols (which `type` changes between) can be found in `textures/map/map_icons.png`:

**1.10-**                           **16w39a+**
[image: Map icons 1.10]  [image: Map icons]

`type` is an integer ranging from `0` (white arrow marker) to `6` (white circle) in 1.10, or to `9` (ocean monument) as of 16w39a.

---

`x` and `z` are world coordinates, showing decorations that have absolute `x` and `z` values being within a certain range of the map's center (dependent on scale). Each scale value increases the range by 63 blocks in each direction.

For example, a map with a scale of 0 created at (0,0) will show decorations with absolute coordinates between -63.0 and 63.0. A scale-0 map created at (512,512) will show decorations between 449.0 and 575.0 (as they are within 63 blocks of the map's center). The same map at a scale of 1 will show decorations between 386.0 and 638.0 (within the 126-block range).

As maps face North, the bottom right corner is the most positive of the two coordinates.

---

`id` must simply be a unique string, to identify the marker by.

---

There's also `rot`, which is clockwise rotation of the symbol in degrees. There does not appear to be a limit on this; `-45` is the same as `315` or `1035`.

---

Here's an example command, provided the map was created at (0,0) and has a scale of 0, with markers at each corner, all facing inwards:

```
/give @p filled_map 1 100 {Decorations:[{id:"7",type:0,x:63,z:63,rot:135},{id:"31",type:1,x:-63,z:63,rot:225},{id:"03",type:2,x:63,z:-63,rot:45},{id:"1",type:3,x:-63,z:-63,rot:-45}]}
```

Expanded data:

```
{
    Decorations:
    [
        {
            id:"7",
            type:0,
            x:63,
            z:63,
            rot:135
        },

        {
            id:"31",
            type:1,
            x:-63,
            z:63,
            rot:225
        },

        {
            id:"03",
            type:2,
            x:63,
            z:-63,
            rot:45
        },

        {
            id:"1",
            type:3,
            x:-63,
            z:-63,
            rot:-45
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh... my. Thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for! How did you find this information?

Comment: Note that as of 16w39a, there are new values 7 through 9.

Comment: As well, the `x` and `z` value *are* absolute coordinates, not local. The values you're using for your example are dependent on the map's created location; if you make a map thousands of blocks out, `x` and `z` must match that because it's absolute.

Comment: DeFazer: Mostly [this wiki page](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#Maps) and some experimentation. @Skylinerw Added the new 16w39a icons. I was teleporting around and giving myself maps, but didn't realize that doesn't center the map in where I am; will fix that.

Comment: I will say that there are quite a few client issues with updating the icons; I have to constantly exit the world in order for them to appear or change, so you might end up having to do that as well.