# How to delete custom symbols on maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I came across a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287153/minecraft-custom-symbols-on-maps) a long time ago that was about custom icons on maps. I can now create custom icons on maps, but I can't figure out how to delete them because I can't even find them in a world's level.dat or similar files.

I also have the question of whether you can remove decorations that have not been assigned an ID.

I searched further and found the following in the NBT data:

[image: MapNBTData]
[image: MapInInventory]

While the information is only stored under "Inventory", I still don't know how it is stored on a server and how it behaves when you put the cards in an itemframe.

Comment: I removed your last question, because one question should only contain… well, one question. The rest is kind of the same thing. Maybe the answer to that also lets you figure out the Aternos one, otherwise just make a new question post. For this one, it would be helpful to have a screenshot from NBTExplorer or whatever you are using.